# We are giving $m$ prizes to $n$ people at lottery...

Tags: probability, combinatorics, probability-theory, inclusion-exclusion

We are giving $m$ prizes to $n$ people at lottery...

**Question A:**
What is the probability that no one will get more then one prize (assume that $n\ge m$).

**Question B:**
What is the probability the all of the $n$ people will get at least one prize? (assume that $m\ge n$).

As I understand it, At the first question we have to use at the "Inclusion–exclusion principle". I'm right? (I know that we have to use the "Inclusion–exclusion principle" at one of the questions [it's the hint])

I'll be glad if you will help me to solve it...
Thank you so much!

Comment: Hint for A: how many ways to give out the prizes in total and how many ways to give out the prizes so $m$ get one each (i.e. how many ways to chose $m$ winners).  That leaves B for inclusion-exclusion.

Comment: @Henryת Thank you. I didn't understand your hint... I'll be glad if you can explain more. BTW, I thing that A should be solved by inclusion-exclusion, B it's a problem at combinatorics, I'm right?

Comment: @Henry, So A is simple? $\binom{n} {m}$?

Comment: Not quite.  First, the order of the prizes may matter, so multiply by $m!$.  Second, to get a probability you need to divide that by the ways to give out the prizes in total i.e. by $n^m$.

Comment: @Henry, sure! First of all the order doesn't matter, so the answer to A is: $$\frac{\binom{n}{m}}{n^m}$$ Thank you!

Comment: And if you can help me with B I'll be glad... Thank you!!

Comment: The order matters in the denominator, so it needs to matter in the numerator.

Comment: @Henry, I dent understnad, what do you mean when you say "The order matters in the denominator".
And if it doesn't matter, how do I cancel it?

Comment: Try with 3 people and 2 prizes, to work out the probability that both prizes go to the same person or the probability that the prizes go to different people

Comment: @Henry, sorry I was unclear... I meant - if the order **matter**, how do I cancel it? Please help me with this... I'm little bit confuse...

Answer (score 0):

I'll assume that the lottery gives each prize to an independently and uniformly randomly chosen person.

For question $A$, there are $\frac{n!}{(n-m)!}$ ways to distribute the prizes to $m$ different people in order, and $n^m$ ways to do so without the restriction, so the probability is $\frac{n!}{(n-m)!n^m}=\prod_{k=0}^{m-1}\left(1-\frac kn\right)$.

For question $B$, apply inclusion–exclusion to the $n$ conditions that each person get a prize. There are $\binom nk$ to choose $k$ particular conditions, and the probability of violating $k$ particular conditions is $\left(1-\frac kn\right)^m$, so the probability of not violating any conditions is

$$
\sum_{k=0}^n(-1)^k\binom nk\left(1-\frac kn\right)^m=\frac{n!}{n^m}\left\{m\atop n\right\}\;,
$$

where $\left\{m\atop n\right\}$ is the [Stirling number of the second kind](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stirling_numbers_of_the_second_kind) that counts the number of (unordered) partitions of a set of $m$ elements into $n$ non-empty parts.